# How to get a random element from multiple elements with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list with some fake sale notification elements. They all have the same class. 
With the code I got, all notifications are shown at the same time but I only need to show 1 random notification each time. How can I do that?

This is my code at the moment:

PHP to generate the elements:

```
$notification .= '
<section class="custom-social-proof">
  <div class="custom-notification">';
    // Get fake sale notification info
    $specarticles = '
    SELECT
    c.alias as content_alias,
    c.title as content_title,
    c.catid,
    c.state,
    c.featured,
    c.images,
    ca.id,
    ca.published,
    ca.title as cat_title,
    ca.alias as cat_alias
    FROM snm_content c
    LEFT JOIN snm_categories ca
    ON c.catid = ca.id
    WHERE c.featured = 1
    AND c.state = 1
    AND ca.published = 1';
    $specarticlescon = $conn->query($specarticles);
    while($specarticles = $specarticlescon->fetch_assoc()){

        $imagesjson = json_decode($specarticles['images']);

        if(!empty($imagesjson->image_intro)){
            $image = 'https://website.nl/cms/'.$imagesjson->image_intro;
        }else{
            $image = '';
        }

        $notification .= '
        <div class="custom-notification-container">
            <div class="custom-notification-image-wrapper">
                <img src="'.$image.'">
            </div>
            <div class="custom-notification-content-wrapper">
                <p class="custom-notification-content">
                    Piet De Graaf - Spijkenisse<br>reserveerde <a href="'.$specarticles['cat_alias'].'/'.$specarticles['content_alias'].'">'.$specarticles['content_title'].'</a>
                    <small>vandaag</small>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>';
    }
    $notification .= '
        <div class="custom-close"></div>
    </div>
</section>';

echo $notification;
```

And my jquery:

```
setInterval(function(){ tpj(".custom-social-proof").stop().slideToggle('slow'); }, 8000);
 tpj(".custom-close").click(function() {
   tpj(".custom-social-proof").stop().slideToggle('slow');
 });
```

I found out you can get something random with `eq`. So I tried the following:

```
var len = tpj(".custom-social-proof").length;
var random = Math.floor( Math.random() * len ) + 1;
setInterval(function(){ tpj(".custom-social-proof").eq(random).stop().slideToggle('slow'); }, 8000);
 tpj(".custom-close").click(function() {
   tpj(".custom-social-proof").stop().slideToggle('slow');
 });
```

But this stops the notification from showing up entirely. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass random inside `setInterval` and hide all element same class toggled.

Please try. Now you need to detect if element is alreay toggle.

```js
var len = $(".custom-social-proof").length;
var random = 0;

setInterval(function(){ 
  random = Math.floor( Math.random() * len ) ;
  $(".custom-social-proof").hide('slow');
  $(".custom-social-proof").eq(random).stop().slideToggle('slow'); 
}, 1000);
```

```css
.custom-social-proof{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="custom-social-proof">1</section>
<section class="custom-social-proof">2</section>
<section class="custom-social-proof">3</section>
<section class="custom-social-proof">4</section>
<section class="custom-social-proof">5</section>
```

Comment: with pleasure :)